# Get all wearable data from healthkit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I want to get step count from wearable devices such as samsung gear fit bit etc from the healthkit api.

I want to know if it is possible to get data of all the wearables from the healthkit itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to Apple, HealthKit provides a central repository for health and fitness data on iPhone and Apple Watch.
>
> Health Kit works only for iOS and WatchOS devices.

If you need to integrate Fitbit data into your iOS App, you need to use their [api](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/basics/).

> According to [Samsung developer page](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch/develop/tech-doc/gear-app-limitation-iphone), Companion applications are not supported for iPhone.